# How to pass parameters in Rewrite Rules with specifying the .php file name?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I have a site, which successfully passes the content after the first slash to a specified .php file. (elegantly: remove ".php")

`site.com/azamat to site.com/azamat.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

How can I add additional parameters to these rules, so I can pass "page" parameters, like:

`site.com/azamat/bagatov to site.com/azamat.php?page=bagatov`

or

`site.com/thisisthefile/andparams to site.com/thisisthefile.php?page=andparams`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these rules (keep the ones you already have):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/.+$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1.php?page=$2 [L]
```

This is more or less like what you've got with the exception of using a `%1` backreference to check if the *first part of the URI* exists as a php file. This is the match for the first part:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/.+$
```

And this is the fheck to see if the `([^/]+)` grouping exists as a php file:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
```

Everything else is to match what's after the first `/` and make that the `page` query string param.